# How to sum up all the leaf nodes of a nested Javascript object array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree

Currently I have a nested Javascript Object array that has many leaf nodes with the same name but different values

```
{
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Central",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Cellophane `Tape",
          "value": 10.528979999999999
        },
        {
          "name": "Cellophane Tape",
          "value": 10.529
        },
        {
          "name": "File Separator",
          "value": 10.529
        },
        {
          "name": "Hard Cover File",
          "value": 10.529
        },
        {
          "name": "Highlighter",
          "value": 10.529
        },
        {
          "name": "Office Chair",
          "value": 10.529
        },
        {
          "name": "Pencil",
          "value": 10.529
        },
        {
          "name": "Tape Dispenser",
          "value": 10.529
        },
        {
          "name": "File Cabinet",
          "value": 21.058
        },
        {
          "name": "Highlighter",
          "value": 21.058
        },
        {
          "name": "Office Chair",
          "value": 21.058
        },
        {
          "name": "Pencil",
          "value": 21.058
        },
        {
          "name": "Plastic Comb Binding",
          "value": 21.058
        },
        {
          "name": "Tape Dispenser",
          "value": 21.058
        },
        {
          "name": "White Board Markers",
          "value": 21.058
        },
        {
          "name": "File Separator",
          "value": 23.273360000000004
        },
        {
          "name": "Binder",
          "value": 23.2734
        },
        {
          "name": "Cellophane Tape",
          "value": 23.2734
        },
        {
          "name": "File Separator",
          "value": 23.2734
        },
        {
          "name": "Hard Cover File",
          "value": 23.2734
        },
        {
          "name": "Highlighter",
          "value": 23.2734
        },
        {
          "name": "Plastic Comb Binding",
          "value": 23.2734
        },
        {
          "name": "Tape Dispenser",
          "value": 23.2734
        },
        {
          "name": "White Board Markers",
          "value": 23.2734
        },
        {
          "name": "Binder",
          "value": 64.0017
        },
        {
          "name": "Eraser",
          "value": 64.0017
        },
        {
          "name": "File Separator",
          "value": 64.0017
        },
        {
          "name": "Office Chair",
          "value": 64.0017
        },
        {
          "name": "Plastic Comb Binding",
          "value": 64.0017
        },
        {
          "name": "Tape Dispenser",
          "value": 64.0017
        },
        {
          "name": "Binder",
          "value": 64.00174
        },
        {
          "name": "Tape Dispenser",
          "value": 64.00174
        },
        {
          "name": "Binder",
          "value": 67.2899
        },
        {
          "name": "Highlighter",
          "value": 67.2899
        },
        {
          "name": "Office Chair",
          "value": 67.2899
        },
        {
          "name": "Plastic Comb Binding",
          "value": 67.2899
        },
        {
          "name": "Tape Dispenser",
          "value": 67.2899
        },
        {
          "name": "Cellophane Tape",
          "value": 74.2509
        },
        {
          "name": "Office Chair",
          "value": 74.2509
        },
        {
          "name": "Pencil",
          "value": 74.2509
        },
        {
          "name": "Plastic Comb Binding",
          "value": 74.2509
        },
        {
          "name": "White Board Markers",
          "value": 74.2509
        },
        {
          "name": "Cellophane Tape",
          "value": 79.7194
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Therefore, what I would like to do is to traverse to all the leaf nodes of this array, then agregate it **ACCORDING to each parent** like so,

```
const agregateDeep = x => {
                  if (Array.isArray(x.children)) {
                      x.children = x.children.map(deep);
                      return x;
                  } else {
                      return {
                          x: x.reduce(function (r, o) {
                              (r[o.name]) ? r[o.name] += o.value : r[o.name] = o.value;
                              return r;
                          })

                      };
                  }
              };
```

Something like this, but using the reduce function returns a flat array. If so,then how do I insert this flat array back into my leaf nodes?

I was able to retrieve ALL leaf nodes and aggregate it, so my expected output is something like this but I want it to be according to EACH parent.

**MY DATA** : https://api.myjson.com/bins/gki6c

**Expected Output :**

```
[
  {
    "name": "Central",
    "children": [
      {
            {"name" : "Cellophane Tape","value":79.7194},
            {"name" : "File Separator","value":64.0017},
            {"name" : "Hard Cover File","value":23.2734},
            {"name" : "Highlighter", "value":67.2899},
            {"name" : "Office Chair","value":74.2509},
            {"name" : "Pencil","value": 74.2509},
            {"name" : "Tape Dispenser","value" : 67.2899},
            {"name" : "File Cabinet","value": 21.058},
            {"name" : "Plastic Comb Binding","value": 74.2509},
            {"name" : "White Board Markers","value": 74.2509},
            {"name" : "Binder","value" : 67.2899},
            {"name" : "Eraser","value": 64.0017}
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can maintain a `hash` for the name and its leaf nodes found
   across the object
2. You can filter the leaf nodes and transform it to what you want,
   check existence in hash, if found add it there and use that array,
   otherwise create a new array, push it there and save the array in
   hash.
3. You can filter out those children having further children, and
   recursively call for each of them (filtered) children to process the
   same logic (it will help you not to call one level of function in
   stack for recursion)

```js
var obj = {"children":[{"name":"Central","children":[{"name":"Cellophane `Tape","value":10.528979999999999},{"name":"Cellophane Tape","value":10.529},{"name":"File Separator","value":10.529},{"name":"Hard Cover File","value":10.529},{"name":"Highlighter","value":10.529},{"name":"Office Chair","value":10.529},{"name":"Pencil","value":10.529},{"name":"Tape Dispenser","value":10.529},{"name":"File Cabinet","value":21.058},{"name":"Highlighter","value":21.058},{"name":"Office Chair","value":21.058},{"name":"Pencil","value":21.058},{"name":"Plastic Comb Binding","value":21.058},{"name":"Tape Dispenser","value":21.058},{"name":"White Board Markers","value":21.058},{"name":"File Separator","value":23.273360000000004},{"name":"Binder","value":23.2734},{"name":"Cellophane Tape","value":23.2734},{"name":"File Separator","value":23.2734},{"name":"Hard Cover File","value":23.2734},{"name":"Highlighter","value":23.2734},{"name":"Plastic Comb Binding","value":23.2734},{"name":"Tape Dispenser","value":23.2734},{"name":"White Board Markers","value":23.2734},{"name":"Binder","value":64.0017},{"name":"Eraser","value":64.0017},{"name":"File Separator","value":64.0017},{"name":"Office Chair","value":64.0017},{"name":"Plastic Comb Binding","value":64.0017},{"name":"Tape Dispenser","value":64.0017},{"name":"Binder","value":64.00174},{"name":"Tape Dispenser","value":64.00174},{"name":"Binder","value":67.2899},{"name":"Highlighter","value":67.2899},{"name":"Office Chair","value":67.2899},{"name":"Plastic Comb Binding","value":67.2899},{"name":"Tape Dispenser","value":67.2899},{"name":"Cellophane Tape","value":74.2509},{"name":"Office Chair","value":74.2509},{"name":"Pencil","value":74.2509},{"name":"Plastic Comb Binding","value":74.2509},{"name":"White Board Markers","value":74.2509},{"name":"Cellophane Tape","value":79.7194}]}]};

function aggDeep(obj) {
  let hasChildren = o => o.children && o.children.length,
    hasNoChildren = o => !(o.children && o.children.length),
    map = {},
    aggDeepRec = ({
      name,
      children
    }) => {
      if (hasChildren({
          children
        })) {
        let leafs = children.filter(hasNoChildren);
        if (leafs.length) {
          let entry = (map[name] = map[name] || {name, children: {}});
          leafs.forEach(le => {
            entry.children[le.name] = (entry.children[le.name] || 0) + le.value;
          });
        }
        children.filter(hasChildren).forEach(c => aggDeepRec(c));
      }
      return map;
    }
  return Object.entries(aggDeepRec(obj)).reduce((res, [k, v])=>{
    let {name} = v,
    children = Object.entries(v.children).map(([name, value])=> ({name, value}));
    return Object.assign(res, {[k]: {name, children}});
  }, {});
}

var res = aggDeep(obj);

console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 4));
```

Comment: Amazing work. Can you add a bit more to your answer? I would love for the leaf nodes to have some label property like name : "Cellophane Tape: ,  value  : 79.7194

Comment: out = [];
 Object.keys(mappedData).forEach(function (d) { out.push({ name: d, value: mappedData[d] }); })

Comment: Something like this perhaps? I would mark your answer as useful if you could achieve this :)

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want. If you can show what exactly output you want, or you can tweak the code accordingly.

Comment: if you see my sample data , the data has "name" and "value" properties. However, in your output , Its just "Cellophane Tape" : 79.7194.

Comment: Updated my question to reflect my needs.

Comment: Ideally, you one shouldn't change/edit the question meaning / question target op, once answer is given / or accepted, or discussed properly, but since you were a little confused about the exact output what you want, and that's just a step deletion in the algo I have updated the answer as per your requirement. Ideally I was creating the one you need and now (default) and transforming to the one you needed earlier, which was different from input format.

Comment: I apologise for that. There is still duplicates in your output. My output is only unique values. Bascially you have to convert the nested array into an array of objects then map it into name and value properties.

Comment: Updated to calculate sum for each entry under a unique name.